# What is the data structure of this variable in perl?

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

I am new to perl and reading a code written in perl. A line reads like this:

```
$Map{$a}->{$b} = $c{$d};
```

I am familiar with hash looking like `%samplehash` and accessed as `$samplehash{a}="b"`

but what does the above line say about what is Map actually?

Comment: what is Map ... refer to perldoc http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html

Comment: Dumping variables greatly helps when you need to understand particular data structures. Just `use Data::Dumper` and later `print Dumper($Map);`.

Comment: @musiKk: I think you mean `print Dumper(\%Map);`

Comment: @yb007: The question was about the variable %Map in the example code, not about the function map.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given these variables:

```
my $a = "apples";
my $b = "pears";
my %c = ("bananas" => 2);
my $d = "bananas";
my %Map;
```

The assignment

```
$Map{$a}->{$b} = $c{$d};
```

Results in a hash looking like this:

```
%Map = (
    "apples" => {
        "pears" => 2
    }
);
```

`%Map` is a hash, which after the assignment contains a hash ref through autovivification: If not already there, the inner hash ref is automatically created by Perl by accessing the element `$Map{$a}->{$b}` in the `%Map` hash.

Answer (score 5):

```
$Map{$a}->{$b}
```

is equivalent to

```
${ $Map{$a} }{$b}
```

which is like

```
$hash{$b}
```

only using the hash reference `$Map{$a}` instead of `%hash`.

See http://perlmonks.org/?node=References+quick+reference for some easy to remember rules about how to use nested data structures.

Additionally, with autovivification on (which it is by default), if `$Map{$a}` starts as not existing or undef, it will be implicitly initialized to be a new hash reference.

Answer (score 1):

the value for key $a in $Map is an reference of associate array which has a key name stored in $b.

`%Map = ( $a => { $b => $c{$d} }, ...)`